# Creating Read only user in AWS Oracle Rds 19c

Tags: amazon-rds, oracle19c

I want to create a user in Oracle 19c which has access to create tables, create indexes, etc.- probably a database owner.

Then I want to revoke write access from the same user so that the user have only read access to the tables in a database.

This ideally means that for the first query the user is a database owner and for all other queries the user is a read only user.

Queries I am using are:

Grant queries:

1. create user xyz IDENTIFIED BY password DEFAULT TABLESPACE "USERS"
   QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "USERS" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
2. GRANT "RESOURCE" TO xyz
3. GRANT "CONNECT" TO xyz

Then there are some create table queries.

Revoke queries:

1. REVOKE "RESOURCE" FROM xyz
2. REVOKE "CONNECT" FROM xyz

For connecting I again gave create session and select access -

1. GRANT create session TO xyz;
2. GRANT select any table TO xyz;

The problem which I am facing is that, after revoking write access I am still able to do write operations (drop, insert, update) on the tables created with this user.

I read something about public user group, but couldn't find a solution. Please help me in finding a solution for the above scenario.

We can safely assume that I have the master credentials to do such operations.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of a schema can *always* manipulate the objects it owns; that access cannot be revoked. If you want read-only access, you must configure that through granting privileges to a separate user.

Typically, a secure configuration would have the owner of the schema (tables, indexes, etc.) locked so that it cannot be used directly, then access to the objects granted through roles - or even better through a PL/SQL API - to other users to allow SELECT or DML operations. The owner of the objects should only be enabled/used when making changes to the schema.

Use of "ANY" privileges like `SELECT ANY TABLE` or the use of the `PUBLIC` schema to grant privileges to all users is generally discouraged in favor of targeted permissions using roles and APIs. Always follow the Principal of Least Privilege and never grant more access to a user than is minimally required.